# The project 'EmailMarketing.Publications' failed to build using EF6 and VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-6

I'm beginning to use EntityFramework 6 Code First in a project developed in Visual Studio 2010. I have a class that derive from DbContext as follow:

```
public class PublicationRepository : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a migration associated with the Publication class. The project builds fine in Visual Studio, but when using the Update-Database command in the Package Manager Console, the build fails most of the time with the following message: `The project 'EmailMarketing.Publications' failed to build.`

In the error window, I see errors about a resx file not found like this one: `Invalid Resx file. Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ExceptionMessages.resx'.` ExceptionMessages.resx is a file found in one of my projects, but it's not in C:\Windows\system32.

My problem is it's building fine in Visual Studio, and by running the Update-Database again I get a different error (about a different resx file) until at one point the command works. Then it starts failing again by pointing at different resx file, until it decides to work again.

Has anyone experienced (and resolved) this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I could find is building the project inside Visual Studio and running the command right after (while it's still compiling). In that case it always works. This will have to do until we can upgrade to Visual Studio 2012 where we don't have that problem.